# Trying to connect to a hosted runtime on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been trying to connect to a hosted runtime on Google Colab as usual. Until now, it worked perfectly, but for some reason right now everytime I press 'CONNECT' it shows up 'Unable to connect to runtime'.

Did anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error? Are errors reported in the [Javascript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/javascript)? Does this behavior persist in an incognito window?

Comment: This behavior doesn’t persist in an incognito window, and there are no errors in the js console.:/

Comment: Try disabling recently installed extensions and/or logging out & back into your Google account. If things work in an incognito window, it suggests a problem with your default browser configuration such an installed extensions or customized settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue sometimes, then I found it happened when I run large work or my running time is pretty long. Colab will prohibit your account to connect. The first time, your account can work after 24 hours. The second time, you will have a longer time penalty.